# Issues with import of microsoft.exchange.webservices

Tags: java, android, import, android-studio, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to use microsoft's exchange webservices in an Android application in Android Studio, but the import of the library is not working.
When i type:

`import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.*;`

`microsoft` is underlined in red and I'm getting the error: `cannot resolve symbol 'microsoft'`.
I've followed this guide for installing ews java api, but I seem to be fudging up somewhere. 
https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api

Anyone that knows of a quick fix or maybe what I've done wrong?

Thanks for all and any help.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:
Copied the `ews-java-api-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` into the /lib/-folder of the Android Project.